# Django - invalid literal for int() with base 10: '''

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '''
```

is the error that is occurring. I am recieving this error whilst trying to update my database to register pcap files.

Following is the line on which the error occurs

```
Pcaps.objects.update_or_create(filename=pcapname, filehash=malwarehash, uuid=uuid)
```

Here is the model into which it is inserting.

```
class Pcaps(models.Model):
     filename = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
     datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
     filehash = models.ForeignKey(Malwares)
     uuid = models.ForeignKey(System)
```

Comment: when you filter by `ForeignKey` in expression need set instance or integer value for the FK, so chek `malwarehash` and `uuid` values

Comment: your problem will be in one of the two parameters uuid or malwarehash, because your error means that you passed error parameter type and I think it is malwarehash, please check it is value and show it to us.

Comment: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ed01ebfbc9eb5bbea545af4d01bf5f1071661840480439c6e5babe8e080e41aa'

Comment: That is the malware hash

Comment: Can you please add your `Malwares` and `System` models?

Comment: class Malwares(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    filehash = models.CharField(max_length=100)

Comment: class System(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    infected = models.BooleanField(default=0)

Comment: Why are you posting your code in comment? Please add it to the question, where it belongs.

Comment: @dipl0 from what you have written in your comment, you are passing to the `update_or_create` method a string, while it requires an instance of `Malwares` and `System` classes, or their corresponding `pk` values. Since you are not passing an instance of any class, django thinks it should be a `pk`, which it tries to convert to an `int` and fails.

Comment: @dipl0 you should get the corresponding `Malware` and `System` instances and pass **them** to the `update_or_create` method and then your code will work.

Comment: Ahhhh makes sense, I think i will try and pass the primary keys to do this. Many thanks. Wouldn't have realised this myself.